# Does concentration gradient or difference in number of particles affect pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, entropy

Suppose I have 2 identical boxes and both of them are divided into 2 equal halves by a board. Now I fill the 2 boxes with different total number of air particles, and with different number of air particles in the 2 halves of each box, so that in box A, the ratio of particles in the 2 halves of the box is 1:19, while in box B the ratio is 991:1009. Both boxes have a difference of 18 particles between the 2 halves, however the concentration gradient in box A is much larger. Is the pressure produced in box A larger than in box B, or do they have the same pressure?
(Assuming uniform temperature and other variables can be neglected)

Comment: What does the ideal gas law predict?

Comment: Same pressure? Since it only depends on number of moles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ched Miller points out ideal gas law (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) states that PV=nRT, with P = pressure, V = volume, n = number of moles, R = constant, T = temperature.
Since V, R and T are the same in all your half boxes, you are left with P = k n, k being a constant.
In other words, pressure will be linearly proportional with the number of particles.
Then the pressure difference in box A will be proportional to 19-1, while the other to 1009-991, 18 in both cases, so same pressure applied on the two boards.